# Graphics display not working on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, gui, graphics, display

I am using CentOS 6.5 but `cat /etc/issue` shows the following

> Oracle Linux Server release 6.8
>
> Kernel \r on an \m

May be I have updated few programs using Oracle repository.
After restart, I get the following message on a command prompt.

> Oracle Linux server release 6.8
>
> lo: Disabled Privacy extensions

I could only get the display screen after entering my account details and through

> startx

Please help me rectifying this..!

Comment: Since you ***may have updated*** stuff which is even vague to you, how are we expected to guess what you did that caused your problem?  The title is very misleading as you obviously can read stuff coming from the machine on your screen.  Look at `/etc/inittab` and look for the default runlevel (line similar to `id:3:initdefault:`).  If it's below 5, change it to 5, restart and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you @JuliePelletier. That worked like a charm. Good to know this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The run-level 3 is the default when you don't have a graphical environment (X).  For a graphical environment, the standard is level 5.

To permanently change the init run-level on your system, you should edit `/etc/inittab`, look for the default run level on a line similar to `id:3:initdefault:`, and change the `3` to `5`.  When you reboot it should load `X`.

You can also switch run-levels manually with the `telinit` command.  (To switch to run-level 5: `telinit 5`.)

Note that the run-levels have been established a long time ago and distributions were developed following these standards.  This is why your CentOS loads `X` when you set the run-level to 5.

Comment: Could you please help me with this situation. 
(http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343371/centos-updated-with-oracle-linux-repositories-causing-problems)